# How to turn off autopair-mode for web-mode in emcs24?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

So when editing Django templates I have noticed that web-mode will auto-complete certain tags.  This is awesome, except that this functionality seems to conflict with autopair-mode by placing an extra close bracket like so:

```
{% block title %}} <--- '%}' closing brace is added by web-mode, second '}' is added by autopair-mode
```

For simplicity's sake I decided to enable autopair-mode globally in my .emacs like so:

```
(require 'autopair)
(autopair-global-mode) ;; to enable in all buffers.
```

Realizing the conflict I added the following `web-mode-hook` to (in theory) disable autopair-mode when entering web-mode:

```
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 
      #'(lamda () (autopair-mode -1)))
```

I am using emacs24 and this should work according to the simple documentation on [autopair-mode's git repo](https://github.com/capitaomorte/autopair)...but I am noticing that autopair-mode is still being enabled by default when entering web-mode.

I am thinking there is some sort of inheritance in elisp that I don't know about...so  I thought I would ask the question here.

For reference, the exact order/snippet from my .emacs is as follows:

```
(require 'autopair)
(autopair-global-mode) ;; to enable in all buffers.

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 
      #'(lamda () (autopair-mode -1)))
```

Comment: This exact configuration works for me just fine. Which version of Emacs 24 are you using (e.g. `24.3`, `24.4.1`)? Have you tried eliminating the rest of your Emacs configuration and just including what you have listed in the question?

Comment: Specifically, I am using `24.3.1` (the latest version in the default `apt-get` package archives).  Eliminating the rest of my Emacs configuration is a logical next step, but also likely leads to some significant time investment. I guess I will go that route when I have a free minute this weekend.